# Calling a datepicker from javascript

Tags: javascript, html

as i've said in the title i got a datepicker library and was wondering how to call it into html 5 this is the code im trying to add it into

```
<div class="form-group">            
        <label asp-for="IncidentDate"></label>
        <input asp-for="IncidentDate" type="date" class="form-control"/>
        <span asp-validation-for="IncidentDate" class="text-danger"></span>            
    </div>
```

The end goal is to change the display of the drop down calender to a more appealing looking one
[I want to change the look of the calender](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvOCT.jpg)

Comment: where did you get the datepicker from?

Comment: @DCR screenshot looks like a standard HTML5 datepicker to me...so built into the browser.

Comment: That datepicker looks like the out of the box html datepicker. Good luck styling that. I would just do a quick google search and see which one is customizable to your needs and go with that one.

Comment: joey I don't think you can alter the appearance of HTML5 datepickers...or not much, anyway

Comment: I have googled it and there are many styles to choose from just unsure how to implement the library into the code

Comment: "unsure how to implement the library into the code". Well, what library is it? Most libraries come with documentation, or at least a "getting started" page that tells you the basics.

Comment: yes i did what the library suggested and it didnt change the calendar

Comment: So.... just going to make people guess what library it is? Because every library has their own quirks...

Comment: its straight from the jquery site jquery-ui-1.12.1-custom is the file name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the standard example provided from the jquery site.  You should look there first.  You need to make sure you've added the links and scripts to bring in the jquery libraries and you need to provide the input with an id of datepicker

```js
 
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 
</head>
<body>
 
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i will give it a try thank you

Comment: feel free to accept my answer if it answers your question so others know its a good solution

Answer (score -1):

From w3 but ADyson is right you can't change the appearance.  If you want to do that try the datepicker from jquery. You can change the input a little [How to change the appearance of input type="date" datepicker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51945122/how-to-change-the-appearance-of-input-type-date-datepicker)

```css
[type="date"] {
  background:#fff url(https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cc_mono_icon_set/blacks/16x16/calendar_2.png)  97% 50% no-repeat ;
}
[type="date"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  display: none;
}
[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  opacity: 0;
}

/* custom styles */

body {
  padding: 4em;
  background: #e5e5e5;
  font: 13px/1.4 Geneva, 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Verdana, sans-serif;
}
label {
  display: block;
}
input {
  border: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  width: 190px;
}
```

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
  Birthday:
  <input type="date" name="bday">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: its has the standard type="date" which gives that dropdown calender which i want to change its look

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of how to implement the datepicker library the OP has...

Comment: look at the html he provides.  looks like the standard. Also look at the darn comments above.  OP is asked to provide the specifics of his datepicker.

Comment: Right, that's the existing code where the OP wishes to integrate the datepicker library.

Comment: i downloaded a library from jquery wbsite if that helps

Comment: Joey, you need to be more specific i.e. provide a link to the download page for the date picker.  Each datepicker is different and will need to look at the specific directions associated with the datepicker you are using

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/download/ is where i got the library